# access javascript in subfolder of parent directory

Tags: javascript, directory, parent

I have a javascript file called as follows:

```
<script src="js/responsiveSlides.min.js"></script>
```

I want to point to a copy of the js file in an equally named folder in the parent directory using the following:

```
<script src="../js/responsiveSlides.min.js"></script>
```

It is failing for some reason. What could be the reason? Both paths exist.

Comment: there is nothing wrong here. can you provide the structure of your files and folder.

Comment: Do You use an backend programing language?Like php,asp or java?!